# CURL on self not working

Tags: apache, curl

I'm dealing with this server that can't seem to call CURL on itself.
To illustrate:

1. I have a localhost server (named http://experiments.local). When I go to terminal and do "curl http://experiments.local", that works.
2. Now I upload all the stuff to this server. (http://www.prod.com). When I ssh to that box and do "curl http://www.prod.com" that just hang.

Is there any setting that says no curl to self? If yes how do I turn that off?

Just to clarify:
calling "curl http://www.prod.com" from my local machine works too. So it's really only when I try doing curl from that same box.

The reason why I need that is because when a user hit the API living in www.prod.com, that API will call a 3rd party vendor that upon failure / success will hit a callback URL that we pass along to them.

Now since, I added this option to my curl call `curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);` the API call just stall. Works fine on my local machine version since my local machine doesn't have that curl hanging issue.

Thank you,
Tee

Comment: how are you calling curl? From a linux command line?

Comment: When you say you upload stuff to the server - is that URL http://www.prod.com actually publicly accessible?

Comment: @dandrew - yes from linux command line when ssh-ed in. On my machine, through mac terminal.

Comment: @calvin - yes the url is publicly accessible.

Comment: Try curl -v -v -v prod.com to get a look at what's going on.  That should help you troubleshoot your failure.

Comment: thanks @calvin, it just prints this. * About to connect() to prod.com port 80
*   Trying 10.10.10.10...

Comment: Can you SSH anything else?  Can you list the contents of your /etc/hosts?

Comment: Sorry, meant to say, can you curl to anything else.

Comment: @calvin, yes from prod.com I'm able to curl to other sites. Just not to prod.com. And I'm able to curl to prod.com from everywhere else just not from prod.com. Makes it sound like curl to self on that box is not enabled, but not sure how to enable that.

Comment: Is this problem solved yet?  Can you paste the contents of your /etc/hosts file?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem here, turns out the solution is quite simple

Open your `/etc/hosts` files and you will find these two lines (the 147.4.12.20 ip is just an example, yours will be different)

```
127.0.0.1     something
147.4.12.20   something
```

Just add your domain to that lines that point to your server, it will be like this:

```
127.0.0.1     something prod.com
147.4.12.20   something prod.com
```